# MongoDB Node.js mongo db node js driver connects and immediately disconnects

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using Linux Mint operating system. When a try connect to MongoDB via Node.js, MongoDB driver connects and immediately disconnects. This doesn't happen when I use the regular MongoDB shell.

MongoDB start command

```
mongod --noauth --port 27017 --dbpath ./db
```

index.js

```js
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";

const client = new MongoClient('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/');

async function main() {
    try {
        await client.connect();
        console.log('Successfully connected to mongodb');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Something wrong: ${error}`);
    }
}

main();
```

mongod server in terminal

```
2024-02-18T11:45:40.890+0500 [conn1] end connection 127.0.0.1:52306 (0 connections now open)
2024-02-18T11:45:41.391+0500 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52320 #2 (1 connection now open)
2024-02-18T11:45:41.393+0500 [conn2] end connection 127.0.0.1:52320 (0 connections now open)
2024-02-18T11:45:41.895+0500 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52336 #3 (1 connection now open)
2024-02-18T11:45:41.897+0500 [conn3] end connection 127.0.0.1:52336 (0 connections now open)
2024-02-18T11:45:42.397+0500 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52350 #4 (1 connection now open)
2024-02-18T11:45:42.399+0500 [conn4] end connection 127.0.0.1:52350 (0 connections now open)
2024-02-18T11:45:42.899+0500 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52358 #5 (1 connection now open)
2024-02-18T11:45:42.901+0500 [conn5] end connection 127.0.0.1:52358 (0 connections now open)
2024-02-18T11:45:43.403+0500 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52360 #6 (1 connection now open)
2024-02-18T11:45:43.405+0500 [conn6] end connection 127.0.0.1:52360 (0 connections now open)
2024-02-18T11:45:43.905+0500 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52364 #7 (1 connection now open)
2024-02-18T11:45:43.907+0500 [conn7] end connection 127.0.0.1:52364 (0 connections now open)
```

I tried all possible ways, but nothing works

Comment: Since you are using nodeJS, you could try to make the connection by running the entire `index.js` file using `node` or `nodemon`. Something like `node index.js`.